# Problems with Google Spreadsheets ImportXML function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm having some problems with ImportXML in my Google Spreadsheet.  I currently have two sheets, each with their own ImportXML, retireving (basically) the same data - the server providing the data has updated their feed service to require the use of a user-specific "key" in the URL to track who is retrieving what.  Prior to this change, my ImportXML worked just fine.  They are about to turn off the non-key feeds, and my spreadsheets are about to break.

In the first (working) sheet, [this is the feed](http://atilla.hinttech.nl/fseconomy/xml?id=18649&key=M3LRG43T&query=GroupLogByMonth&month=10).

I can import the data sucessfully by using the following syntax in cell A1:

```
=importXML(ʺhttp://atilla.hinttech.nl/fseconomy/xml?id=18649&key=M3LRG43T&query=GroupLogByMonth&month=10ʺ,ʺ//GroupLogByMonthʺ)
```

In the new (non-working) sheet, the URL to the feed (including my user-specific "keys") is [here](http://atilla.hinttech.nl/fseconomy/data?userkey=85AHFXVQIC&format=xml&query=flightlogs&search=monthyear&readaccesskey=YGTWNDAXV7&month=10&year=2012).

I am unable to create a working importXML on this sheet.  None of my attempted Xpath queries worked, except "*"; but that resulted in all elements being lumped into a single cell.

I have shared my spreadsheet file (link is in the comments below - I am unable to post more than 2 links) with each of these sheets so that the above examples can be seen and played with.  Any advise on the non-working sheet would be wonderful.

Comment: I see that my question was cleaned up a bit by Nathaniel Ford, adding hyperlinks to my pasted urls, but my link to my shared spreadsheet was removed... was that against the rules?

Comment: Okay, well here is the link [to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmGGITW0iKSNdGdhelppXzRxRFUtMWFPTlpsNVR3RkE) @NathanielFord , please let me nkow if this is against the rules - not sure why you removed it.

Comment: I didn't remove any links; if I did it was in error. You should feel free to put the link to the spreadsheet back into the original quesiton at the appropriate place.

Comment: Ten years after, the question links are broken

Answer (score -1):

In the new XML feed there is no tag "GroupLogByMonth". This might explain why your Xpath query won't return anything when you look for that.

Did the format of the XML change too, next to the new URL?